# How to add a Spinner inside a tableview cell in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

How can I add a Spinner inside all the tableview's cells that can increase and decrease an Int value in my SQL database?

It's similar to this image: 
Spinner inside a tableview example

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is required to write your own **TableCell**.
For example, I can provide my one, which, depending on the stored value, displays different pictures in the cell. In the *setGraphic* method, you can set any javaFX element.

```
public class IncreaseTableCell extends TableCell<Position, Boolean> {

    public IncreaseTableCell() {
        super();
    }

    public static Callback<TableColumn<Position, Boolean>, TableCell<Position, Boolean>>
    getCellFactory() {
        return e -> {
            IncreaseTableCell cell = new IncreaseTableCell();
            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item != null)
            setGraphic(StructureGUI.getIcon(item ? "up" : "down"));
    }
}
```

Further, to use the written TableCell in table, it is required to add when setting up the table:

```
column.setCellFactory(IncreaseTableCell.getCellFactory());
```

Comment: What does this have to do with spinners? Furthermore the kind of logic used in your `updateItem` implementation is flawed: If the cell becomes empty, the content remains...

Comment: @fabian, I think, the main question was how to insert something unique into the table cell. I have indicated the direction in which it is required to work in order to find a solution to the question. I provided an example of how I implemented this for another case. And in it at null value there should have been an empty cell :)